# Clear data of a particular NSUserDefaults object Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsuserdefaults

In my project I am using `NSUseDefaults` for store data with the different objects.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults1=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//---- I have set object for this

[defaults1 synchronize];

NSUserDefaults *defaults2=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//---- I have set object for this

[defaults2 synchronize];
```

Now I want clear all keys data only for `defaults2`, not for `defaults1`. So whenever I am applying below code:

```
NSDictionary *defaultsDictionary = [defaults2 persistentDomainForName: appDomain];
    for (NSString *key in [defaultsDictionary allKeys]) {
      NSLog(@"removing user pref for %@", key);
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
```

Above code have remove value for `defaults2` but also for `defaults1`. But I don't want to remove objects for `defaults1`. So please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults is like a singelton class so it will always return the same shared system object.

You can store multiple objects using multiple keys and can delete/remove objects against those keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [read a doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSUserDefaults/standardUserDefaults) about `NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults` you should know that standardUserDefaults **Returns the shared defaults object.** and actually defaults1 and defaults2 the same.

You can store keys and then delete only those keys like:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults1=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//---- I have set object for this

[defaults1 synchronize];

[[defaults1 dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys]; // use this keys for deleting
```